# How to perform x509 authentication, when I want to validate the trust only on certain calls in spring boot

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, x509certificate

I'm looking to enable x509 authentication on my SOAP server but it should be relevant only on certain calls.

*i.e call 1 - **no auth**, call 2 onwards- **need auth**. 
if call -1 happens again, again **no auth**.*

Does Spring boot offer any means to build this customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way out from this hurdle is to disable the checks @ the trust manager (i.e configure a trust manager that does NO checks) and pass-in that responsibility to **point cuts** defined before individual service methods (only the ones that need it).

The **points cuts** is made to fallback to the trust-store to verify the permit for the caller.